# Handling click events in GridView cell with Spinner

Tags: android, xml, gridview, spinner

I use the following code to catch a click on a gridview item cell. That works fine.

```
grid_main.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
grid_main.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    }
});
```

I then added a Spinner object inside of the gridview cell. Now, I can click on the Spinner object but the containing gridview cell does not respond to a click anymore. I am assuming the Spinner listener is replacing the gridview listener. Both gridview and spinner listeners work fine alone but together I have the problem. I need to be able to click on both. Below is the spinner code:

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.driver_list);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DispatchMonitorCalls.this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, driverlist_name);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { 
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int arg2, long arg3) {
    }
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
} 
});
```

Below is the layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/driverrow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_locationtype"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"        
        android:text="Empty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_timestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_locationtype"        
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_locationtype"
        android:text="Empty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_locationtype"        
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_timestamp"
        android:text="Empty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff8080" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/driver_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_locationtype"        
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_status"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you can not figure this out, you might want to try an ugly approach. Create an onItemClickListener for the Spinner, which simply calls the onItemClickListener of the GridView item.

Comment: Clicking on a cell usually opens another screen with detailed information in it (more than the few lines provided in the cell view). The spinner is just a shortcut to the most commonly needed feature (they pick a name out of the list and it takes action on it). If they take that action, it is not necessary to open the additional view as the work has been completed. If I take the spinner away and put it inside the other screen (detailed view), then I may have another issue because that screen also contains a listener.

Comment: This seems like it would be a common problem but I have not located threads with this issue.

Comment: OK. Solved. I had to kludge it. I added an OnClickListener to each of the textview's contained in the gridview cell and removed the listener from the gridview itself. It now works. Not sure why the other method does not work but cannot spend a lot of time with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call "blocksDecendants" on your relative layout, because the spinner is clickable, it steals the focus of your view, and thus your "click event" gets flown away

try this :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/driverrow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" //<-- add this line, and your click event will be responded 

android:gravity="left" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_locationtype"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"        
    android:text="Empty"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_timestamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_locationtype"        
    android:layout_below="@+id/row_locationtype"
    android:text="Empty"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_locationtype"        
    android:layout_below="@+id/row_timestamp"
    android:text="Empty"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#ff8080" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/driver_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_locationtype"        
    android:layout_below="@+id/row_status"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" />
```